# Why won't Learned Darian sell to me?

Tags: geneforge-2

I found Learned Darian in Darian's Sanctuary, but I did it after completely clearing the Rising Bridge map (directly to the east), including dueling and killing the mad battle beta there, as well as wiping every other enemy off that map.

Darian refuses to sell to me, saying she needs the items for defense of the sanctuary while the battle alphas to the east is are around. As I said, I fully cleared that map and already killed the battle beta. The [walkthrough on GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/918441-geneforge-2/faqs/26410) suggests Darian will give you a quest to kill the battle beta and sell to you once you complete it, but she's not actually giving me a quest.

Did I screw this up by essentially completing the quest before she could give it to me, or is Rising Bridge not the area she's talking about? I'm especially confused since the FAQ says "kill the battle beta to the SW", but Learned Darian herself says east, and indeed there was a battle beta in the zone directly east.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out that there is a different path in the dialogue tree that I hadn't taken, which leads to her giving the quest, which I could then immediately tell her I'd completed.

On the really small chance someone else runs into this, here's how you get the quest. When talking to her select the following:

1. "What do you do out here?"
2. "You are having a problem with some rogues?"
3. "You support the killing of a fellow creation?"

That should give you the quest. After that, when you talk to her the option to turn in the quest should be in the top level of her conversation tree.